# Common lisp how to print strings that contain "øæåè" etc

Tags: unicode, format, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

What format directive shoud use to print the string, e.g "J'T'Emmène Au Vent" without escape characters?

To me it seems that "~a" directive should work, but it does not.

```lisp
(format t "~a" "J'T'Emmène Au Vent")
```

prints `J'T'Emm\303\250ne Au Vent`.
The expected output is `J'T'Emmène Au Vent`

Note: I use SBCL

Comment: Where do you print this output to?

Comment: Those are octal character escapes.  I assume that you are trying to print to a display/terminal/buffer without the right character support, so that the output is correct, but the display seems broken.  What kind of terminal, REPL, editor, or IDE are you using?

Comment: Im using emacs with SLY. The terminal supports unicode chars without a problem. If i run `(format t "J'T'Emmène Au Vent")` it prints the characters without the octal character escapes. However, when the string is passed as an argument to format it prints the with the octal character escapes.

Comment: Call your string `s`: is `(string= (format nil "~a" s) s)` true?  If it is not that's a bug in `format`, if it is then there is probably some confusion about streams and/or the Emacs interface.

Comment: It works fine if i run SBCL from a regular terminal. So probably something borked with the emacs interface.